# Unable to update to Fedora 27 due to composer?

Tags: fedora

I'm trying to update from Fedora 25 to Fedora 27 using the GUI but when the download is done, I get an error message saying:

```
Error running transaction: package composer-1.6.3-1.fc27.noarch has unsatisfied Requires: (php-composer(composer/ca-bundle) >= 1.0 with php-composer(composer/ca-bundle) < 2)
package composer-1.6.3-1.fc27.noarch has unsatisfied Requires: (php-composer(composer/semver) >= 1.0 with php-composer(composer/semver) < 2)
package composer-1.6.3-1.fc27.noarch has unsatisfied Requires: (php-composer(composer/spdx-licenses) >= 1.2 with php-composer(composer/spdx-licenses) < 2)
package composer-1.6.3-1.fc27.noarch has unsatisfied Requires: (php-composer(psr/log) >= 1.0 with php-composer(psr/log) < 2)
package composer-1.6.3-1.fc27.noarch has unsatisfied Requires: (php-composer(seld/cli-prompt) >= 1.0 with php-composer(seld/cli-prompt) < 2)
package composer-1.6.3-1.fc27.noarch has unsatisfied Requires: (php-composer(seld/jsonlint) >= 1.4 with php-composer(seld/jsonlint) < 2)
package composer-1.6.3-1.fc27.noarch has unsatisfied Requires: (php-composer(seld/phar-utils) >= 1.0 with php-composer(seld/phar-utils) < 2)
```

The odd thing is, I don't think I have Composer installer (tried to do `dnf remove php-composer composer`, nothing found).

How can I do?

Here's my current `uname -a`:

> Linux pc-cyril 4.13.16-100.fc25.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Nov 27 19:52:46 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I tried to add the `--allowerasing` command, without much luck.

Comment: I have also had the same problem. I have raised a bug about it, https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1551543, which has confirmed it as a real problem, rather than a figment of our imaginations or (at least my) ineptitude. I had previously tried removing phpMyAdmin as this also showed up for me as a problem, but with no success. There are other workarounds suggested in responses to that bug report

Comment: Good to know we are not alone on this :) Thank you @Markers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem today, when upgrading from Fedora 26 to 27.

Solved by uninstalling first phpMyAdmin :

```bsh
rpm -e phpMyAdmin
```

*Note :* At this point, RPM creates backup of 2 config files. Maybe you should do your own copy for safety :

- /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php.rpmsave
- /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf.rpmsave

Now, you can redo the dnf command for system upgrade which previously failed, then continue the upgrade and reboot process.

When your system is back, simply reinstall phpMyAdmin :

```bsh
dnf -y install phpmyadmin
```

Then, put back your own config files. 
*Note :* I kept the newly installed phpMyAdmin.conf which seems better that the backuped one.

Finally, restart httpd service.

Answer (score 1):

I have now found the process that works.

Performing

```
dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=27 --disablerepo=updates --no-downgrade
```

allowed me to then reboot and upgrade without removing any packages. This gave me an "initial" Fedora 27, but `packagekit` showed over 1300 updates available. Unfortunately using the UI popup to perform the upgrade failed the same as before. So using the sequence:

```
dnf upgrade rpm; dnf upgrade dnf; dnf distrosync
```

then allowed me to restart into an up-to-date Fedora 27.